# Spark Tutorial for Avro

Tags: apache-spark

I've started with Spark and my use case is to read Avro file  (data source) and perform ETL based on rules. As a start I just wanted to try reading the AVRO and create an RDD. Based on a recommendation in one of the stackoverflow sites I `

```
object abc {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = 
  { 
    //val master = Properties.envOrElse("MASTER",args(0))
    val path = args(0)
    val sparkContext = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("My-spark-app"))
    val jobConf = new JobConf(sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
    val rdd = sparkContext.hadoopFile (
        path, 
        classOf[org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroInputFormat[GenericRecord]],
        classOf[org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroWrapper[GenericRecord]],
        classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable],
        10)

    println(rdd.first)

  }
}`
```

My environment is CDH 5.1.3. I'm getting the following error.

```
15/03/17 08:53:58 INFO YarnClientClusterScheduler: YarnClientClusterScheduler.postStartHook done
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/avro/mapred/AvroInputFormat
        at com.scif.afw.abc$.main(abc.scala:30)
        at com.scif.afw.abc.main(abc.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:292)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroInputFormat
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

I've built the project using Maven and my POM has the Avro jar and I can see the class in the jar.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using yarn cluster, there could be avro jar present from yarn.application.classpath. NoClassDefFound could be caused by multiple instances of the same class in classpath(1 from your jar and 2nd from default yarn app classpath)